# How to correctly import a module with module.exports = { default: ... }?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor, javascript-import

The JS version of my project's Cypress config has

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default;
```

This works fine. But I thought the `import` equivalent should be

```
import cucumber from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';
```

and this results in

```
TypeError: (0 , cypress_cucumber_preprocessor_1.default) is not a function
```

Looking at the module's code I see it exports like this:

```
const preprocessor = <an arrow function>

module.exports = {
  default: preprocessor,
  transform,
};
```

In my `tsconfig.json` I have

```
"module": "commonjs",
"esModuleInterop": true,
```

I found two workarounds which work, but I don't like either:

Option 1:

```
import cucumber_ from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor';
const cucumber = cucumber_.default;
```

which doesn't pass TS typechecking, it thinks `cucumber_` is the default exported function.

Option 2: keep the old version with a type assertion

```
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default as (options?: any) => (file: any) => Promise<string>;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The first variant should've worked. But try `import { default as cucumber } from 'cypress-cucumber-preprocessor'`

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine I had tried that, it gives the same `TypeError`.

Comment: How about `import cucumber = require("…")`?

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine That's a different error: `TypeError: cucumber is not a function`, and `console.log(cucumber)` shows it's `{ default: [Function: preprocessor], transform: [Function: transform] }`.

Comment: At this point my best guess is that Cypress uses some internal `tsconfig.json` to compile the config file, and it has some settings which don't work with this case.

Comment: You can also type module augmentation. I have only tried it with untyped modules so far though, so there might be some conflicts.

Comment: It's really weird that *cypress-cucumber-preprocess* exports `{ default: preprocessor, transform }` and not [`{ default: preprocessor, transform, __esModule: true }`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50943704/1048572). This is apparently at odds with the TypeScript declarations it provides. I'd consider this to be a but in the library

Comment: @Bergi Yes, probably. It's a very old version, too, I was planning to upgrade later.

Comment: @Bergi And the example in Allen's answer there clearly shows the reason for the error I get.